# ESC Pos Flutter. How to print to thermal printer immediately after one is finished?

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to print using esc_pos_bluetooth twice. But when I called the function to print twice, of course it is error because the printer still printing the first function call

> Error. Another print in progress

How to work around this ? Thanks in advance